# teamviewer quick connect button with qt creator

Tags: wine, teamviewer

first, i am using centos 6.9, and qt creator 3.0.0
I am able to connect with server using terminal directly with command

```
/usr/bin/teamviewer -i [serverid] -P [password]"
```

then i was implement it to a button in qt with this code :

```
system("gnome-terminal --hide-menubar --profile=noclose -x bash -c '/usr/bin/teamviewer -i [serverid] -P [password];'");
```

but thats not work, it show this error :

```
Init...
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default.
XRandRWait: Started by user.
Checking setup...
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/bin/wineserver: Symbol `wine_casemap_upper' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/bin/wineserver: Symbol `wine_casemap_lower' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Launching TeamViewer ...
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/bin/wineserver: Symbol `wine_casemap_upper' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/bin/wineserver: Symbol `wine_casemap_lower' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
```

i am also tried with different method using Qprocess .start .execute, still no luck.

Comment: I changed the tags a bit since it seems to be a teamviewer and/or wine issue, not a C++/Qt/centos issue. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46316605/edit) them again if you feel it was not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved it myself.
i have installed wine in system and i guess i have deleted it correctly, but not.

it happened because I am not deleted all wine commponent correctly.

i just remove wine with `yum remove wine`,
then it solved with `yum remove wine*`.

btw thanks to [@nwp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484570/nwp) to change my tag question to wine and teamviewer only. Thats make me to recheck the wine package on my system.